# Fix Mouse in VirtualBox VM to use it freely in host-system without moving the "vm-mouse"

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have a VirtualBox VM set up with Windows 10 (host is also running on Win10) - now I can switch my Mouse between the host and the vm as usual (moving the mouse into the VM-window and clicking on it enables me to click in my vm).

What I'd love to do now is set a hotkey (or something similar), so that the mouse does not move in my virtual box any more. As an example:

I target the center of my VM-window with my mouse - if I now want to do something on my host system, the "VM-mouse" follows my "host-mouse" to the border of the VM-window. What I want is the mouse to stay centered in my VM while I "free" my mouse to be unsed in the host system.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Which pointing device mode (PS/2 mouse, USB tablet, etc.) are you using in the VM's settings? Does the VM have VirtualBox "Guest Additions" installed or not? What two icons are shown at the bottom-right corner of the VM window?

Comment: While there are caveats, if you have guest additions installed, you can typically get similar behavior by pressing `Right Ctrl` while in the VM.